# Using microsoft office controls outside of microsoft office?

Tags: wpf, winforms, ms-office, controls, autohotkey

I'm trying to grab actual microsoft office 2013 or later (2016) controls, like context menus, ribbons, dropdown lists, combo boxes, etc. as gui elements in an AHK script using COM or whatever way I can, to use OUTSIDE of MS office applications.
There are some 3rd party "look alike" control-frameworks out there I found, not interested in those right now until I rule out using the real thing.

In order to dig into this I'm trying to identify if it's even possible to get my claws on a native MS office controls outside of office, all I know so far is that it probably has to do with .net and COM, can anybody give me a starting tip?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has made the Ribbon control available to public. You can use it in your applications.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877